# Semantic operator of dot in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'd like to understand a bit better the 2 functions below. I know it is very compact and understand more or less what it does: it converts each characters of a string into string of '0' and '1'. But...
How does the dot(in front of encodeToByteArray) connect the 's' to encodeToByteArray()?
Where can I find more info about what dot represents?
Also, how and why the code `{ byte -> binaryStringOf(byte) }` can do the job in that place?
How does it "know" that there is a byte with which it calls the function `binaryStringOf(byte)`
Where can I find more info about it, too?

```
fun binaryStringOf(message: String): String {
    var s: String
    s = (message)
        .encodeToByteArray()
        .joinToString("") { byte -> binaryStringOf(byte) }
        return s
    }
fun binaryStringOf(b: Byte): String {
    return b.toString(2).padStart(8, '0')
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
.encodeToByteArray()
```

works on the incoming string (`message` in this case). It [returns](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/encode-to-byte-array.html) a [ByteArray](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-byte-array/); so something that represents an **array** of Byte values.

And on that array object, it invokes the [joinToString()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html) method. That method receives various arguments, but only the separator string (`""`) is provided, and the `transform` parameter.

Now: `transform` is a **function**. It is something that can be **invoked**, with parameters, and that has to return a specific result.

The key part to understand is that `{ byte -> ... }` is that `transform` function parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The formatting above makes things a little bit more confusing, but let me try to explain what is going on.

The `=` is an [assignment operator](https://www.w3schools.com/kotlin/kotlin_operators.php). It says "assign the variable `s` to the result of the expression on the right side".

Now we see that `message` is a parameter in the `binaryStringOf` function of type `String`. `String` is a [class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html) which contains a [function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html) (also called a method when it is a member of a class) called `encodeToByteArray` [which returns a `ByteArray`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/encode-to-byte-array.html).

`ByteArray` in turn has a function called `joinToString` which we're giving two parameters: one of type `String`, and one of type `((Byte) -> CharSequence)` (ie, the function is itself being passed in as a variable, using lambda syntax). [Kotlin has some syntactic sugar to make this look nicer when the lambda is the last argument](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#passing-trailing-lambdas).

So, the statement

```kotlin
    s = (message)
        .encodeToByteArray()
        .joinToString("") { byte -> binaryStringOf(byte) }
```

means "the variable `s` is assigned the value that results from calling `joinToString` on the result of calling `encodeToByteArray` on `message`.

Then `return s` says that the return value from the `binaryStringOf` should be whatever value was assigned to `s`.

Comment: How can 'byte' in { byte -> binaryStringOf(byte) } identify each byte in the byteArray created by .encodeToByteArray()?

Comment: The lambda that gets passed into `joinToString` is run against every byte of the ByteArray. It is similar to calling `forEach` on a list, for example. You could achieve the same result using a `for` loop for every byte in the byteArray

Comment: Looking at the source code may help clarify. https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/common/src/generated/_Arrays.kt

`joinToString` calls the more generic `joinTo`, which has a `for (element in this)` loop, which calls the transform on every element (via `buffer.append(transform(element))`)